# Respecting or using your father

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

In shulchan aruch yora daiya 240.6

> היה צריך על שום דבר בעיר ויודע שישלימו חפצו בשביל אביו אע"פ שיודע שגם כן יעשו בשבילו לא יאמר עשו לי דבר פלוני בשבילי אלא יאמר עשו בשביל אבא כדי לתלות הכבוד באביו:

My guess on a translation

> If you need anything in the city and you know that your wanting will be fulfilled for your father even though you know that it will also be done for you (my understanding: that you do not need to use his name), do not say do for me this thing for me but you should say to it for my that, do that to hang (relay) the respect on his father

Please help me understand, I live in America I do not know authentic respect

To me it seems that it is saying you should not ask for the favor for yourself (so that they should respect you by doing what you want) but for your father (so that they should respect your father by doing it for him

To me it seems that the father (and not you) will now owe them for this respect (hakoras hatov)

Please tell me were am I wrong

Comment: The son isn't asking for a favor in the context of a quid pro quo. The assumption is that the favor is being granted out of respect. If the son mentions his father, he is implying that his father is worthy of respect. If any reciprocity was expected, it would be from the son anyway.

Comment: @fred I do not really understand

Comment: Option (1): "Please do me a favor out of respect for my great father. I may not be worthy of the favor myself, but please do me this favor for my father's sake." Option (2): "Please do me this favor. Perhaps you wouldn't do this for just anybody, but do it for my sake." If they will do the favor for you in either case, you should choose Option (1) since it demonstrates the esteem you have for your father, and it suggests that the other person also esteems your father. (Is this clear?)

Comment: @fred thank you for your patience, what you wrote now yes, but why "if eny reciprocity ... It would be from the SON" if he is doing it for the father

Comment: That was just an incidental remark. My point was that everyone involved understands that the son is the one benefiting from the favor. So if the other person really expects a favor in return, he will go to the son. This wouldn't necessarily have anything to do with who was being shown respect by the initial favor (or in the request for the initial favor).

Comment: @fred thank you, 2 things are still not clear to me 1. What does is mean  a third person does somthing out of respect 2. In the siif it does not clearly say for the respect of my father it just says for my father

Comment: If the father will hear about this will he not be responsible to do "hakoras hatov" for what was done for his son

Comment: 1. I just meant the third person does the favor because he thinks the father is worthy (or at least the son shows deference to his father by suggesting that as the reason the third person should do the favor). 2. You're right; I just gave one example of how the son can express the idea. The main point is that the son shows respect by indicating that his father is deserving of the favor. 3. Any father should want to express *hakaras hatov* to someone who help's his child regardless of the reason for the favor. But the son is the main one who should show gratitude anyway - he received the favor.

Comment: By the way, commentaries on the *Shulchan Aruch* indicate that the son should ask for a favor this way even if he knows that the person is going to do the favor only for the son's sake. This is because the son is showing respect for his father by suggesting that his father is more worthy of receiving the favor.

Comment: @fred am I correct in this? If I go into a store and am looking for somthing, I need to tell the worker please help me find this for (respect) of my father? (Or what?, please give me a few practical examples) thank you

Comment: I suspect that this would only apply to situations where (1.) the person knows (or knows of) your father, and (2.) the person is not required to help you. In the case of a worker at a store, it is likely that neither of these conditions would apply. Also, it may be that this *halacha* wouldn't apply where invoking one's father would seem inappropriate rather than respectful (e.g. "Please hire me for this job for my father's sake. *wink, wink*"), along the lines of some commentaries that say one should avoid mentioning one's father if it will cause גנאי.

Comment: @fred Please give my a practical example where this will apply

Comment: *Yitzchak*: "Berel! I am in great need of an *esrog*! On your trip to the city, please bring back a nice *esrog* for me. I know this is a great favor, but please do me this favor for the sake of my venerable father!"